# Phone not detects headphones remove

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, huawei, headphones, headphone-jack

My Huawei Y560-L01 not detects native headphone removing anymore. Icon with headphones remains visible. I think I got another problem related to first one - no ring tone is visible and I getting many missed calls. When I restart phone everything works fine. How to solve problem without restarting phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this icon in my status bar?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145770/what-is-this-icon-in-my-status-bar)

Comment: Also, the question-and-answer format of this site works best if you [put each question in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154). Please [edit] your post down to one question, and create new posts to ask any further questions. You'll get better answers that way.