# What is this type of headphone icon in notification bar?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notification-icons, headphone-jack

My phone (LG G3) shows two different types of headphone icons. They are the leftmost icons in the images below. The first is a normal headphone icon. What is the second one?

I think it might be USB headphone, but that doesn't make sense, because I don't have USB headphones and never use USB headphones with the device.

I have noticed sometimes when I use the aux cable for my car, it displays the second icon instead of the first one. It shows the first icon whether I use headphones with a built-in mic or headphones that don't have a mic - it's the same icon.

Image 1: normal headphone icon

[image: screenshot of notification bar with normal headphone icon]

Image 2: ??

[image: screenshot of notification bar with unknown icon]

Any thoughts?

*Edited images to make them smaller*

Comment: @Rahul I saw that question. My icons do not look like that one, though, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Line-out is different from headphones - probably that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @AndyYan I think you're right as is the selected answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second one is showing a *line out* or *[auxiliary audio](https://www.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/2f20rw/plugged_in_my_g3_with_my_logitech_z506_51_system/)*
 icon, which means that it had recognised that a jack had been plugged in ( but it doesn't detect a speaker or maybe it detects the speaker ) but fundamentally to *differentiate*  between  regular headset (with or  without mic) and speaker connected with line out

If this happens when you connect to regular headphone, it indicates some dirt or pocket flint , preventing recognition of head phone. Cleaning with a tooth pick , ear bud and blowing air to dislodge muck should fix. If it doesn't, try app mentioned here 
[What is this icon in my status bar?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145770/what-is-this-icon-in-my-status-bar)

Later versions of LG also differentiate between headphone with speaker and without speaker

I had this icon show up on a Dopod phone, owned a decade ago